# Busybox exits instantly printing 'SIGUSR1'

Tags: linux, signals, router, busybox

I was tinkering with my router these days. It runs on MIPS core and the OS is based on Linux. But the builtin busybox is very limited. I managed to export a binary of busybox compiled for MIPS through telnet. After changing chmod to executable, when I try to run the binary with command './busybox-mips', it instantly prints 'SIGUSR1' on the terminal and terminates. What is wrong here? How can I successfully run this new Busybox binary?

Comment: Please help to solve this...